# how to rewrite-target context path within and without trailing slash?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Im trying to solve context routing in kubernetes nginx ingress

when i enter context path 
`/foo/bar`
in app controller received
`/bar`
it's correct 

but when i enter `/foobar` in app controller received `/bar` but it not supposed to route.

I try `/foo//?(.*)` it's correct but if i enter `/foo` (without slash) it became an error `404`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello.info
    http:
      paths:
      -  backend:
           serviceName: hello-svc
           servicePort: 80
         path: /foo/?(.*)
```

so i expect that `/foo` or `/foo/` should go to `/`

and `/foo/bar` go to `/bar`

and `/foobar` get an `error 404`

and `/foo/bar/hello` should go to `/bar/hello`

Comment: Which Ingress controller version are you using?

Comment: nginx-ingress-controller:0.22.0

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3148) will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this annotation instead:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

and the following path in config:

```
 path: /foo(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: Trying exactly this approach and still having the same error as the author.

Comment: @user2273663 did you found a solution? Having the same issue and are forced to use the trailing slash.